# Ubuntu can't connect to WPA2 but dual-booted Windows can

Tags: networking

I recently changed my router from WEP to WPA2 and also changed my password. Previously I could connect to my wifi via ubuntu but now I cant. Now the weird thing is that the same pc which I have dualbooted with Windows can instantly connect with this wifi, so I assume it has nothing to do with my hardware. I've been struggling with this issue for quite a while and have tried a few things, but that escalated in me corrupting my ubuntu tonight... I reinstalled ubuntu, this time 15.10, and I thought, well maybe I can connect to my wifi this time, but no... Seems I can't. A friend of mine suggests it has probably something to do with my drivers but I don't know how to check that kind of stuff. If any of you could help me out,I would be very grateful. Oh and perhaps one last useful fact: I can connect to another wifinetwork that I can reach from my house with ubuntu. But not with mine :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,I think it's a Ubuntu driver problem in managing the WEP/WPA2. Try to do a test disabling your WiFi protection to check if this is the problem. Try also with other WiFis, maybe it's a problem of your own router.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, I can connect to a wifi from another router but my windows can connect to my own wifi. So can it be a problem of my router then? As for the protection. I will try that tomorrow (its 1AM lol) but I want a wifi connection with protection if possible haha :)

Comment: Hey, I fixed it and it had kindof something to do with your hint :D In my router configuration I can choose for an authention type, I had the possibilities open-system, shared-key or auto. I had selected auto which worked fine on all systems (and I assume it chose shared-key automatically) but on Ubuntu it didn't work. Anyway choosing shared-key fixed my problem. Thanks for the help!